# meteor reactive client: How to correctly change template parts on connect and disconnect events

Tags: jquery, meteor

See described sample project. This very simple code just show a green or red (class `success` or `danger`) div block and text with connection status like `ON` or `off`.

9 from 10 times it works as expected when you FULL RELOAD (Shift - F5) Browser page.

BUT sometimes the text shows `ON` but the div still has class danger as pre-defined in html source.

This is happen because, the event `Template...rendered` fires later than `Meteor.status().connected`.

I want to omit to check at two places wether the classes has to be exchanged.

I already tried to move the lines `...removeClass().addClass()...` inside the `Template...rendered` or the `Template...connection_status` function.

In any case, sometimes the div stays RED.

The browsers console will show log in such situation as:

> [Log] SET CLASS SUCCESS (connection.js, line 10)
>
> [Log] TEMPLATE RENDERED (connection.js, line 24)

**Q: Does someone knows a better solution for this than duplicating the class check?**

Remark: Yes, I know, you could solve this sample problem by using spacebars and write something like `class="alert alert-{{connection_alert_type}}"`

But I am looking for a general solution in combination with jQuery UI, so that there also could be a transition like `switchClass`.

**Q: Will it be an option (and how to do) to invalidate and re-render the template on connection state change?**

---

Test the sample yourself

#### create meteor sample app and add packages by meteorite

1. mrt create sample
2. cd sample
3. mrt add bootstrap-3
4. mrt add jquery
5. rm sample.*
6. mkdir client
7. cd client
8. create files `client.html` and `client.js` as listed
9. mrt

---

#### client.html

```html
<head>
  <title>connection</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{> connection_tpl}}
</body>

<template name="connection_tpl">
  <div id="connection-div" class="col-sm-12 alert alert-danger">
        <div><label>Connection Status:</label>{{connection_status}}</div>
  </div>
</template>
```

#### client.js (works only 9 of 10 or less):

```js
// save reference to div element
var Div_Connection = undefined;

Deps.autorun(function () {
  // be reactive on Meteor connection
  var connected = Meteor.status().connected;

  // switch classes on connection
  if (connected) {
    console.log("SET CLASS SUCCESS");
    if (!_.isUndefined(Div_Connection))
      Div_Connection.removeClass('alert-danger').addClass('alert-success');
  } else {
    console.log("SET CLASS DANGER");
    if (!_.isUndefined(Div_Connection)) 
      Div_Connection.removeClass('alert-success').addClass('alert-danger');
  }
  // set session reactive flag
  Session.set("connected", connected);
});

Template.connection_tpl.rendered = function () {
  Div_Connection = $(this.find("#connection-div"));
  console.log("TEMPLATE RENDERED");
}

Template.connection_tpl.connection_status = function () {
  return Session.get("connected") ? "ON" : "off";
}
```

---

This is my current solution, but I do not like the style :-(

#### client.js (works, but duplicated check - not performant? two times transition maybe?)

```js
// save reference to div element
var Div_Connection = undefined;

var check_Classes = function(connected) {
  if (connected) {
    console.log("SET CLASS SUCCESS");
    if (!_.isUndefined(Div_Connection))
      if (!Div_Connection.hasClass('alert-success'))
        Div_Connection.removeClass('alert-danger').addClass('alert-success');
  } else {
    console.log("SET CLASS DANGER");
    if (!_.isUndefined(Div_Connection)) 
      if (!Div_Connection.hasClass('alert-danger'))
        Div_Connection.removeClass('alert-success').addClass('alert-danger');
  }
}

Deps.autorun(function () {
  // be reactive on Meteor connection
  var connected = Meteor.status().connected;
  // switch classes on connection
  check_Classes(connected);  
  // set session reactive flag
  Session.set("connected", connected);
});

Template.connection_tpl.rendered = function () {
  Div_Connection = $(this.find("#connection-div"));

  // switch classes on connection
  check_Classes(Session.get("connected"));  

  console.log("TEMPLATE RENDERED");
}

Template.connection_tpl.connection_status = function () {
  return Session.get("connected") ? "ON" : "off";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nice solution, a few suggestions:

1. Why have the first `Deps.autorun`, why not just call `Meteor.status()` in the helper?
2. You need to make sure that any `Deps.autorun` get stopped, if you start one in `.created` or `.rendered` you can assign them to the template instance, and then stop them on `.destroy`

---

```
  Template.connection_tpl.rendered = function () {
    var Div_Connection = $(this.find("#connection-div"));
    this.computation = Deps.autorun(function () {
      var connected = Meteor.status().connected;
      Div_Connection.toggleClass('alert-danger', !connected).toggleClass('alert-succes', connected);
    });
  }

  Template.connection_tpl.destroyed = function(){
    if (this.computation){
      this.computation.stop()
    }
  };

  Template.connection_tpl.connection_status = function () {
    return Meteor.status().connected ? "ON" : "off";
  }
```

Comment: Hi Nathan, thanks for your suggestion. You are absolutly right that the first `Deps.autorun()`is not neccesary in this sample case. It was taken out of my current project where I need such a `Session` value and left it in.

One question is still left for me:

Q: Do I also need to stop the `Deps.autorun()` outside a `.rendered` or `.created` method?

I thought that I "could" do this (if the usecase defines that) but other wise it still will run forever.

Is that correct understanding?

Comment: If your `Deps.autorun` is outside any functions etc, then you don't _have_ to stop it...  eg. If there's no risk it could be run again (and doubled up) like the rendered block, then there's no need to tear it down.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes life is so easy.

Thinking about this problem, I came to the conclusion just to add the `Deps.autorun()` two times.

Once for updating our Session value and second for updating classes right INSIDE the `Template...rendered` method. Herefore pretty sure that all neccessary elements are already created inside rendering.

This is (from my perspective) the right way:

---

#### client.js

```js
// this one checks for Session value
Deps.autorun(function () {
  // be reactive on Meteor connection
  var connected = Meteor.status().connected;
  // set session reactive flag
  Session.set("connected", connected);
});


Template.connection_tpl.rendered = function () {
  var Div_Connection = $(this.find("#connection-div"));

  // this one checks for class exchange
  Deps.autorun(function () {
    // be reactive on Meteor connection
    var connected = Meteor.status().connected;
    // switch classes on connection
    if (connected) {
      console.log("SET CLASS SUCCESS");
      Div_Connection.removeClass('alert-danger').addClass('alert-success');
    } else {
      console.log("SET CLASS DANGER");
      Div_Connection.removeClass('alert-success').addClass('alert-danger');
    }
  });

  console.log("TEMPLATE RENDERED");
}

Template.connection_tpl.connection_status = function () {
  return Session.get("connected") ? "ON" : "off";
}
```

---

#### client.js (the short without the console.log)

```js
// this one checks for Session value
Deps.autorun(function () {
  var connected = Meteor.status().connected;
  Session.set("connected", connected);
});


Template.connection_tpl.rendered = function () {
  var Div_Connection = $(this.find("#connection-div"));

  // this one checks for class exchange
  Deps.autorun(function () {
    var connected = Meteor.status().connected;
    if (connected) {
      Div_Connection.removeClass('alert-danger').addClass('alert-success');
    } else {
      Div_Connection.removeClass('alert-success').addClass('alert-danger');
    }
  });
}

Template.connection_tpl.connection_status = function () {
  return Session.get("connected") ? "ON" : "off";
}
```

Comment: In any case, please be aware and have a look on the accepted answer from Nathan. He has improved and corrected my answer, especially that the computation should be stopped, if template will be destroyed.